# Lottie - setProgress is not working properly

Tags: java, android, animation, progress, lottie

I have an animation using Lottie that works fine, the problem is, let's say that my animation is a ball that grows and shrinks (like if it's beating), when the user press the ball, I need it to 'grow to be at its maximum size' so I'd need to set my animation progress to 1 (right?).

This works fine, but the problem is that I want the ball to 'grow' until it gets to its maximum size, not just go from 0 to 1 in a fraction of a second, does anyone know how to do this? (sorry if my question is kind of not well formulated...)

Here's the code that I tried to write: (this code makes the ball go from 0 to 1 in a fraction of a second and not like if it's growing)

```
    LottieAnimationView unclickedAnimation = ...

    unclickedAnimation.pauseAnimation();

    float currentProgress = unclickedAnimation.getProgress();

    for(float i = currentProgress; i < 1.0f; i += 0.01f) {
        unclickedAnimation.setProgress(i);
    }
```

Thanks already

Answer (score 1):

With your currect code you just set the animation to show a specific frame. You want to set the maxProgress and then play the animation.

So if you want it to go from half size to full size you would start with a ***maxProgress(0.5f);*** and pause it there. When the users clicks you set the new parameters:

```
 unclickedAnimation.setMaxProgress(1f);
 unclickedAnimation.resumeAnimation();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am able to understand your question correctly, I think all you need to do is play your Lottie animation on click of the `LottieAnimationView`. The following code may help you understand.

Say your animation json goes from smallest ball size to largest, then -

```
     unclickedAnimation.setOnClickListener(v -> {
              unclickedAnimation.playAnimation();
});
```

Furthermore if you want to loop or set the max frame/ min frame for your animation, you can use -

```
 unclickedAnimation.loop(true);
 unclickedAnimation.setMaxProgress(/*value here*/);
```